# Check if new table entry has overlap with existing tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints, check-constraints

I'm trying to write a constraint to check whether a new entry in my table has an overlay with already existing entries.

this is my code to add the constraint which doesnt work:

```
ALTER TABLE tour
    ADD CONSTRAINT UC_tour
    CHECK (SELECT 1
    FROM tour t2 
    WHERE (tour.starting_time, tour.starting_time + tour.duration) NOT OVERLAPS (t2.starting_time, t2.starting_time + t2.duration)
    )
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tour (
  id  INTEGER,
  Starting_Time TIME,
  Duration      INTERVAL,
  Price         NUMERIC,
  Weekday       DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

It should not let me add new entries with an overlapping tour time

Comment: [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):  *CHECK ...Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row (see Section 5.4.1). The system column tableoid may be referenced, but not any other system column.*. You will need to add a trigger that raises an exception.

Comment: You want an EXCLUDE constraint.  I can't show you a working example, because your example doesn't make much sense to me. What is a time range supposed to represent?  What happens if the range spans midnight?

Comment: Have a look at this:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258036/211987